# Which one is better to use on Making a FakeDbSet HashSet Or ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1

While I was reading [Programming Entity Framework: DbContext](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449312969) on Creating an `IDbSet` Implementation "Julia Lerman" uses the `ObservableCollection` for making the fake `DbSet` items but I've seen on other implementations [like this one](https://gist.github.com/783ddf75f06be5a29a9d) which is pointed on the same book also it uses `HashSet` for items. 
Which one is better to use and why?